# How to create a jpeg using set of div with backgrounds - PHP/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, image

The final output of the image looks like this below.

[image]

If you look into html parts, It's create using different divs as below. All the div are placed one on one using CSS and making the position to absolute.

```
<div id="tproduct" class="timage" style="z-index: 30; background-image: url('main-mask.png') ;"></div>
<div id="tdesign1" class="timage" style="z-index: 20; background-image: url('design1.png');"></div>
<div id="tdesign2" class="timage" style="z-index: 20; background-image: url('design2.png');"></div>
<div id="tmaincolor" class="timage" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="tembellishment" class="timage" style="z-index: 10; background-image: url('flower.png');"></div>
```

If we look at separately it will look like this below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

etc

My question is how can I create a single image using above set of divs and images? I can use PHP or jQuery?

I only want the steps or guidance how it should be done.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is going to work like you want.  It doesn't appear that the images you have use the lighting/shading from the original.

Comment: yes it works. What I want to know is how get a final output as a one image? combining all into a one

Comment: actually you don't need JS or PHP to implement overlapping. You just need to know some CSS basics and put one file on top of another. The top file should be PNG I assume to have alpha-channel

Comment: From my understanding he's looking to create a file, not a rendered effect in the browser.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm able to get a final image as shown in the 1st image. What I want to know is how get a final output as a one image? combining all into a one.

Comment: google for "html canvas compositing" and "html canvas save image"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you would do like this:

1. declare the final image (which will combining all into a one) with

   $final = imageCreateTrueColor($final_width, $final_height);
2. start combining all the images into `$final` with `imageCopy` using
   alpha blending, started from the "farther" from the observer.
3. at the end, you obtain the single final output as a single image with

   imageJPEG($final, $outputFileName, $quality);

You only asked for "steps or guidance", however you also must be careful:

- the elementary images might be *sprites*. In that case you will have to "cut out" from each image the area you're interested in. `ImageCopy` can do that for you too.
- images might not be the proper size and you will have to use `ImageCopyResampled`.
- the manipulations required to exactly duplicate CSS transparency might not be available using GD functions, and you will have to look into imageMagick PHP extension.
- the background image ("flower") might be a **repeated pattern**. If its size is less than the main mask's, you will have to cycle in horizontal and vertical to cover all final image with the background texture.

Comment: Looks like it's not easy as I thought. If you have to a tutorial or sample code please be kind enough to post it here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) in PHP to manipulate the image like you want. From your pictures, I guess that you will have multiple layers, each layer should be multiplied by your "clothing" (to get the shading right) and then you apply them one on top of the other to create the final jpg.

You would have to load your images using `imagecreatefrompng`, `imagecreate` to create the final jpg and a succession of (I assume) `imagecopy` to load your layers one after the other.

Comment: I'm able to get a final image as shown in the 1st image. What I want to know is how get a final output as a one image? combining all into a one.

Comment: You will probably not be able to save your image from the browser, unless HTML5 has a feature I'm not aware of that would allow you to do it. I believe your better option is to construct the image (jpg or png - as you prefer) in PHP by reproducing your div sequence (load the images and copy them to a buffer in the order of their Z Order)